# Difference between DebuggerDisplayAttribute and DebuggerDisplay

Tags: .net, attributes

```
[DebuggerDisplayAttribute("{_name}")]
```

vs

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{_name}")]
```

Is there a difference? Is one an alias of the other? Does VS automatically check for a class named fooAttribute when using an attribute named foo?

Comment: C# allows you to elide the "Attribute", because every attribute is supposed to end with that.

Comment: @Eric: That is an important point I am missing in the existing answers: This is working for every attribute, even for custom ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. The standard convention in naming the class is to append the word Attribute, as in:

```
public class AlertAttribute : Attribute {}
```

When using the attribute, the standard convention is to eliminate the word, as in:

```
[Alert()]
```

From *Attributes (C# and Visual Basic)* at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx

> By convention, all attribute names end with the word "Attribute" to
>   distinguish them from other items in the .NET Framework. However, you
>   do not need to specify the attribute suffix when using attributes in
>   code. For example, [DllImport] is equivalent to [DllImportAttribute],
>   but DllImportAttribute is the attribute's actual name in the .NET
>   Framework.

Answer (score 9):

They are the same, the C# compiler will be able to resolve the type whether you write Attribute at the end or not.

Answer (score 5):

They're the same.  You tend to see the fully qualified name in generated code, especially that output via CodeDom.

You can use either one.  The compiler generates the same thing in the end.